# How to access WPF datagrid Template Column?

Tags: wpf-controls

I'm using WPF 4.0... I created a custom control like decimal textbox... I had inserted that decimal textbox in datagrid template column... Now my problem is that,

How to access that template column or that decimal textbox in Code behind( C#)????

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

In xaml:

```
<DecimalTextbox x:Name="MyTextBox" />
```

In Code-behind:

```
MyTextBox.MyProperty
```

Comment: I don't think that works, I am trying to do the same thing, the issue is that the userControl is inside the DataTemplate, even when I give it a name, I can't access it.